# Footer with TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, footer

I'm updating an app someone made a couple of years back and I'm trying to add a footer visible all the time. I'm working on adding it on one of my activity, but here's the result:

[image]

Here is my .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- Footer -->
<include layout="@layout/footer"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_items"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="22dp" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my line that calls it

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.list_items, mRegions));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have to create a layout with a `ListView` (`id="@id/android:list"`) and place your footer into it, with `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

Comment: Where would you had that?

Comment: Post your footer's layout